# Where is my fault

Tags: html, css

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Satya</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   </head>
   <body margin="0">
     <div class="topheader">
        <div class="banner">
           <img src="../img/header2.png" alt="header banner" width="100%" height="15%"/>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Where is my fault that i am not getting the banner at 15% of the page. I also have tried an external style sheet but that's also not working. if i remove doctype declaration from code than its absolutely working.

help me getting it right.

`

Comment: Please improve your title and clarify the problem. [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="../img/header2.png" alt="header banner" style="width: 100%, height: 15%" />
```

width and height attributes support only pixel size, not percentage

Comment: true... and in addition, in this context, percentage is relative to container width

Answer (score 1):

You can either change your html to this

```
<img src="../img/header2.png" alt="header banner" width="100%" style="height: 15vh"/>
```

Or if you want to use % units, add this CSS in a separate stylesheet.

```
body, html, .banner, .topheader {
  height: 100%;
}
```

vh units, in the first example, set the heigh to 15% of the screen height. Using 15% as a unit, will set it to 15% of the parent container, but your image parent does not have a fixed height, so CSS does not know how to compute this. By giving the parents of the element a fixed height this allows the image to take a percentage height.

If it were me, I would just use a separate stylesheet and add this:

```
.topheader img {
  height: 15vh;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lcn0wf4/